# How to use gulp with the new mvc6 tag helpers for different environments?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, gulp

I am getting completely lost on this concept. I'm working on learning the new ASP5/MVC6 patterns, and wanting to do the following:

- Use `<environment>` helpers in my `_Layout.cshtml` to include only full vs minified source based on environment
- Using Gulp to inject the source into the correct `<environment>` helpers
- Triggering this injection locally when I build/change source, AND how this works in a production environment (Azure)?
- Is my `wwwroot` directory supposed to be static files that are servable to the browser ONLY? IE: I'm putting my source `site.js` and `site.css` in here... but should I put those source files somewhere else and use Gulp to build them and then place them in the `wwwroot`?

My project structure looks like this:

```
/site
  /wwwroot
    /css
      site.css
    /js
      site.js
    /img
      logo.png
    /lib
      /bootstrap
      /jquery
  /Controllers
  /Views
  project.json
  bower.json
```

My `_Layout.cshtml` has:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <environment name="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment name="Staging,Production">
        <!-- How to inject minified version here? -->
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        @RenderBody()
    </main>

    <environment name="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment name="Staging,Production">
        <!-- How to inject minified version here? -->
    </environment>
</body>
</html>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28259746/449688) for setting the ASPNET_ENV, although I'm not sure if it is still valid/up-to-date.

My real frustration comes from:

- Setting up Gulp to simply build my source js/css, minify it, and output it so I can reference it from my html.

Note: pointing to 3rd party libraries is easy, since I can just hardcode it in the `<environment>` helpers. It's just my own source that I'm not sure what the best practice is to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gulp to minify and concat your files and output the bundles inside `wwwroot`.

Then in your `_layout.cshtml`, you can use the `asp-append-version` tag helper to append a hash of your file to the URI for cache-busting. Here, I am bundling the third party scripts together with`site.js`, but you can minify them separately if you want; the concept is the same...

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/bundles/js/site-bundle.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Here's an excerpt from the gulpfile that's doing the bundling and minification (it's a modified version of the one that comes from [generator-aspnet](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet))...

```
var paths = {
  js: [
    webroot + "lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    webroot + "lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    webroot + "js/**/*.js"
  ],
  minJs: webroot + "js/**/*.min.js",
  concatJsDest: webroot + "bundles/js/site-bundle.min.js",

  // ...

};

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.js.concat(["!" + paths.minJs]), {
    base: "."
  })
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

I have a full working sample here:
https://github.com/bigfont/asp-net-core-vnow/tree/master/App06Bundling

Comment: link is broken. please fix it.