# Configuring .NET Core web application launch settings without Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am following the .NET Core RC2 documentation and most of the information is written considering Visual Studio 2015. However, they also released Visual Studio Code and I can also run applications from the command line.

When I develop a application where I don't have VS2015, I am unable to

1. Hookup `launchSettings.json` to my application
2. Change the launch settings e.g. `Hosting Environment`, `launchUrl`, or default `port 5000`, etc.

How do I set these properties if I am developing without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely possible to build a .NET Core app without Visual Studio. Visual Studio Code or the `dotnet` CLI can handle everything you need to do, it's just a little different.

As far as I can tell, `launchSettings.json` is Visual Studio-specific. From the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html):

> This file holds settings specific to each profile Visual Studio is configured to use to launch the application, including any environment variables that should be used.

You'll need a different way of setting the options you want:

**Binding address and port**

This can be configured when you bootstrap your application in `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:8080") // name and port to listen on
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

**Hosting environment**

From the same [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html):

> ASP.NET Core references a particular environment variable, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to describe the environment the application is currently running in. This variable can be set to any value you like, but three values are used by convention: `Development`, `Staging`, and `Production`.

Just set the appropriate environment variable for your platform to "Development", "Staging", "Production", etc. ASP.NET Core will read the value and all the `IHostingEnvironment` logic will work.

In Windows, you can set environment variables in the [GUI](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) or on the command line:

```
setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"
```

**Launch URL**

Visual Studio tries to be helpful by opening the browser automatically for you when you run your application. If you're using `dotnet`, you'll have to do this manually.

I haven't tried it, but this plugin for Visual Studio Code might give you that functionality: [Visual Studio Chrome Debugger](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug)

Comment: **Hosting Environment**, actually I went thru this line earlier, however unable to change, as not sure from where to change this setting without VS2015, as if you see documentation shows VS2015 project's properties window.

Comment: @AviKenjale It's a normal system environment variable. I edited my answer to include instructions.

Comment: Yes. Got it. meanwhile I got too to set these variable from command line as `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` and this change in not a global change, **scope of this change is only limited to current session of command line.**

Comment: @AviKenjale That's what `set` does. Use `setx` if you want to set the value permanently.

Comment: @NateBarbettini, is there a less invasive way to deal with binding address and port that doesn't involve changing Program.cs? Something done at runtime... How does Visual Studio do it?

Comment: Your answer referenced "Hosting_Environment", but the docs no longer mention that variable; they reference `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, right?  "ASP.NET Core references a particular environment variable, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to describe the environment the application" . [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258227/how-to-set-environment-name-ihostingenvironment-environmentname/30314719#comment66418143_30314719)  suggests "Hosting:Environment is for **pre RC2 version of ASP.NET Core**"  Can we update your answer?

Comment: @TheRedPea Yes, I didn't catch the change. Feel free to update.