# What are the differences between the environment variables in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Going through documentation for (ASP).NET Core, I come across multiple environment variable names that seem to do virtually the same, or at least similar, things.

However, I'm having a hard time finding any detailed information on what exactly differs between:

- **Hosting:Environment**
- **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT**
- **ASPNET_ENV**

Is this server-specific (IIS vs Kestrel, for example), or is it relating to something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***ASPNET_ENV*** is legacy and has been removed, use 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' instead. It was announced in this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144#issuecomment-195539322) and pr: [Rename environment variables to ASPNETCORE_.](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/640)

***Hosting:Environment*** was used in RC1 as replacement for ASPNET_ENV, and now is also  legacy. See this [ASPNET_ENV variable should be changed in docs to Hosting:Environment](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/706) issue for more details.

[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) is used to describe the environment the application is currently running in. This variable can be set to any value you like, but three values are used by convention: `Development`, `Staging`, and `Production`.

Comment: Do you know if Hosting:Environment is still relevant, or is it superfluous/abandoned?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Set!