# How does IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName work?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, development-environment, .net-core, production-environment

In a .NET Core console application, if I add the following line...

```
IHostingEnvironment env = new HostingEnvironment();
Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName);
```

I get this result...

> Production

But when I do the same thing in an ASP.NET Core application on the same machine...

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName);
}
```

I get this result...

> Development

- How exactly does EnvironmentName work?
- How can I specify that my local machine is a **Development** environment?
- How can I specify that Azure is a **Production** environment?

---

As an extra point, can EnvironmentName be configured to work with **Debug** and **Release** configurations within the solution?

[image]

- Debug   => Development
- Release => Production

The ultimate goal is to be able to connect to a local SQL database when built using **Debug**, and an Azure database when built using **Release**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Environment Name (IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258227/how-to-set-environment-name-ihostingenvironment-environmentname)

Comment: @Hackerman that's certainly helpful. I've added an extra bit to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How exactly does `EnvironmentName` work?

.NET Core reads the name [from an environmental variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30314719/1108891).

> How can I specify that my local machine is a Development environment?

Set the environmental variable to `Development`.

> How can I specify that Azure is a Production environment?

Set the environmental variable to `Production`.

> As an extra point, can `EnvironmentName` be configured to work with Debug and Release configurations within the solution?

You can create a launch profile that sets the environment name and use that profile with either Debug or Release configuration. The launch profile impacts the `EnvironmentName` when you launch from Visual Studio; you will need to use other means to set it, when you run the app in other environments.

The image below shows running the application in Release configuration and a MyDevProfile that sets `EnvironmentName` to `Development`.

[image]